# NUnit3TestExecutor converting tests but is not running them

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, console-application, nunit-3.0

Trying to get my unit test to run but after clicking "run tests", I just get "NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases" in my output.  The test tries to run but just ends up loading forever till I have to manually cancel the process.  Any idea what could be causing this?

```
using NUnit.Framework;
    using CalculatorApp;
    using System.IO;
    using System;
    using NUnit;



    namespace Tests
    {
        public class Tests
        {
            [SetUp]
            public void Setup()
            {
            }

            [Test]
            public void Test1()
            {

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    Console.SetOut(sw);
                    CalculatorApp.Program.Input1();
                    string expected = string.Format("Type a number, and then press Enter", Environment.NewLine);
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected, sw.ToString());
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your use of `Console.SetOut` I'm assuming you are testing a console program. I'm also assuming that it waits for input from the user.

Unfortunately, it is not getting any input from your code, so it hangs.

Testing a console app by driving it's input and output is possible but complicated. You would usually need to launch it in a separate process, monitor the standard and error outputs and drive the input. Most people do not test this way - at least not those experienced with unit testing.

A better approach is to test the backend that does your calculations.

There's one other complication I should mention... NUnit itself takes control of console output. For that reason, your test would need to save the current output setting and restore it before exiting - otherwise, NUnit's continued processing will be broken.